# Reverse Geocoding: Get city and country

Tags: php, reverse-geocoding

I want to use reverse geocoding to get the city and country of coordinates.

Here are two examples:

[Hamburg, Germany](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.5510846,9.9936818&lang=en)

[Bangkok, Thailand](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=13.7251097,100.3529126&lang=en)

I always need the first `address_components` and then the two types with the values `[ "locality" ]` and `[ "country", "political" ]` but I don’t know how to target them.

What I have so far:

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . get_wpgeo_latitude( $post_id ) . ',' . get_wpgeo_longitude( $post_id ) . '&language=de';
$data = @file_get_contents( $url );
$jsondata = json_decode( $data, true );

print_r( $jsondata['results'][0]['address_components'][0]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get city and country try this

```
foreach($jsondata['results'] as $r) {
    foreach($r['address_components'] as $n) {
        if($n['types'][0] == "locality" && $n['types'][1] == "political") {
            $city = $n['long_name'];
        }

        if($n['types'][0] == "country" && $n['types'][1] == "political") {
            $country = $n['long_name'];
        }
    }
}

echo $city. ", ". $country. "</br>";
```

Comment: What happens when the loop does't enter the `if` condition? How to handle the `else` ?

Answer (score 1):

To get a more accurate and direct result, you could explicitly query for `locality` and `country` results. To do so, you'll need to add the parameter `result_type`.

Using your code, the end result will be:

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . get_wpgeo_latitude( $post_id ) . ',' . get_wpgeo_longitude( $post_id ) . '&result_type=country|locality&language=de';
```

This will obtain ONLY `country` and `locality` entities in the answer. Being much more efficient, fast, lightweight and accurate.